# How to replace deprectaed notifyProperty?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Currently I have a getter xyz that is computed. To schedule a new computation I call `notifyProperty(this, #xyz);`.

In the the latest version of *observe*, `notifyProperty` is deprecated. How can I replace it? The documentation suggests to use `this.notifyPropertyChange(#xyz, oldValue, newValue);`. The problem is, that I don't have the `oldValue` (and not directly the `newValue`) as the getter is computed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [suggestion from the devs](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/WJfH3bjri_s/SkSp4MUXDCUJ) is to keep the `oldValue` around in a private variable for reference. As for the `newValue` you can actually just pass the getter and it will compute it with the new values.

You will be looking at a class similar to this:

```dart
class MyElement extends Observable {
  @observable var foo, bar;
  var _oldValue;
  @reflectable get xyz => foo + bar;

  MyElement() {
    // we use the xyz getter to compute its own new value
    // notifyPropertyChange returns the new value for convenience :)
    notifyXyz() { _oldValue = notifyPropertyChange(#xyz, _oldValue, xyz); }
    onPropertyChange(this, #foo, notifyXyz);
    onPropertyChange(this, #bar, notifyXyz);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would you keep the `oldValue` around when dealing with Lists?

Comment: Whatever is passed as the last value of notifyPropertyChange will be returned by the function. If you pass the full list (instead of the changed index) you can continue with this method. But instead of using `onPropertyChange` you will need to do: `myList.changes.listen((_) { _oldValue = notifyPropertyChange(#xyz, _oldValue, xyz); });`