# Object.watch() Dart equivalent

Tags: dart

I wish to know if Dart has an implementation equivalent of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [observe](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/observe/0.12.1+1/index.html#observe/observe) package might do what you want.

See also for an example

- [Functionality in parent class needs to detect changes to child class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111714)
- [Implement an Observer pattern in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186198)
- [How to use Dart ChangeNotifier class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774215)
- [How to replace deprectaed notifyProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549049)
- [Dart: Using observale with multiple getters/setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941265)
- [Observe package from polymer dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24276737)